# Location address1_city,address2_stateorprovince,address1_country,address1_county tracking

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

In `[organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts` the address information  address1_city, address2_stateorprovince, address1_country, address1_county are entered having related to any parent entity type. Like address1_country is mapped with list of countries. Or possible to retrieve all address data with associate relationship.

Example:
  US country having NY as state.

Comment: could you please elaborate your question? What exactly you wish to achieve?

Comment: I need to save all the location details to my local database.So i need the different country and their states and county,city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use the `customeraddresses` entity to pull data from Account/Contact address records.

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/customeraddresses?$select=city,county,stateorprovince&$filter=city ne null
```

Still for the distinct values, you have to [follow my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287644/7920473).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done directly with API call, because there is no related entity for Address (out of box) for Account.

You will have to try slightly different approach.

I would use console Application or c# for this.
Fetch all the Account and it's address details,
Then filter out the fetched data as unique w.r.t Country.