# Dynamics crm remove the repeated data while fetching via api

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

Trying to retrieve all state under one particular country.

URL:

```
api/data/v9.1/leadaddresses?$select=stateorprovince&$filter=stateorprovince ne  null and country eq 'US'&$count=true&$orderby=stateorprovince
```

Problem here is it returns data like this

```
"value": [
  {
"@odata.etag": "W/"166729382"",
"stateorprovince": "AK",
"leadaddressid": "691de670-aa45-426b-8fee-00b3a7f7e469"
},
  {
"@odata.etag": "W/"166729369"",
"stateorprovince": "AK",
"leadaddressid": "12db5897-dc53-44ae-b4aa-03c5486ad6ac"
},
  {
"@odata.etag": "W/"166729416"",
"stateorprovince": "AK",
"leadaddressid": "f64ccf06-fa67-421a-aa5f-0469302be1c2"
},
  {
"@odata.etag": "W/"166729206"",
"stateorprovince": "AK",
"leadaddressid": "b1f9ce4a-a06b-4d7d-befc-04bea0d41a4e"
},
  {
"@odata.etag": "W/"166729323"",
"stateorprovince": "AK",
"leadaddressid": "a4b9ff56-2d24-4957-b09b-04ef6ce56304"
},
```

Any way to remove the repeated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use fetchxml to get distinct values, that is the only option.

```
<fetch top="50" distinct="true" >
  <entity name="leadaddress" >
    <attribute name="stateorprovince" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="stateorprovince" operator="not-null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

You can use web api endpoint and use the above fetchxml like below:

```
https://crmdev.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/leadaddresses?fetchXml=<fetch top="50" distinct="true" >   <entity name="leadaddress" >     <attribute name="stateorprovince" />     <filter type="and" >       <condition attribute="stateorprovince" operator="not-null" />     </filter>   </entity> </fetch>
```